# AngularJS unit testing: Constructor Test: Windows Azure Invoke Api

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, azure, jasmine, azure-mobile-services

I am making an Hybrid App using Ionic(AngularJS).
I have a generic factory which uses an `invoke Api` method of `WindowsAzureService` JS SDK. And I am unit testing my application.

```
var mClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl,applicationKey);

mClient.invokeApi(api, data, header)).done(function (res) {
   // do something 
})
```

I am not using `$http`, so I can't mock test cases with a `$httpBackend`. I would like some help on how to test api calls using windowsAzureServices.

Also how to I spyOn this constructor?

[Github link to SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk/Javascript)

Comment: I don't know anything about WindowsAzureService, but the easiest way would probably to wrap the client into an injectabla servicereturning promises, to spy on that service in your tests, and to make it return resolved/rejected promises, based on what you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a test harness for Mobile Services. You'll want to follow JB Nizet's advice and create one which can mockup the results you expect.

Alternatively, you can call the API directly and set the appropriate ZUMO headers for auth. Then you can use `$http` and `$httpBackend`. It's worth checking out Mobile Services GitHub and looking at how they run E2E tests against the client. You can probably use something similar.